# How do I use JavaScript with Ruby rack?

Tags: javascript, ruby, rack

I am not a web programmer and I am still learning about rack. I know how to work the simplest lobster example that just uses call(env) and returns a bunch of HTML.

How do I use javascript and css with this? Where do I put my .js and .css files? And for that matter where do I put my image .jpg files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that main purpose of rack is handling of HTTP requests. Rack has handlers that allow it to connect to all web application servers (WEBrick, Mongrel etc.) But handling of static types of content - js, css, pictures - is the aim of web servers. One of the Rack's purposes - is to be a bridge between servers and Ruby web frameworks (Rails, Sinatra etc.)

**UPDATE**

If you want to handle static file with rack's help, you can use [Rack::Static](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Static.html) class. For example, I have following folder structure:
/my_rack_folder
 |_ config.ru
 |_ my_app.rb
 |_/media
   |_test

```
**** config.ru ****
require './my_app'
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/media"]
run MyApp.new

**** my_app.rb ****
class MyApp
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Hello from the Rack World!"]]
  end
end
```

and test - static file. Now you can run rack using rackup `rackup config.ru` - by default it start on port 9292 with WEBrick server. If you open your browser by address `localhost:9292`, you will see text rendered by my_app.rb file, and by address `localhost:9292/media/test` - content your static file.

Comment: I am slightly confused by this. So there is an underlying webserver that rack is simply invoking? If the only thing I am (consciously) running is Rack, which web server is being run? And how do I add pictures?

Comment: I've updated my first message, I hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: OK This is the information I needed to start googling. Thanks! And yes, I definitely got your message about the diff between rack and webrick, if I weren't saddled with all these legacy code and the "I want it last Thursday"'s, I'll take the time to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting to venture into JS and CSS and trying it out on Rack perhaps it's time to move to something like [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot try anything out. I am saddled with a legacy app and the only thing I know is that it runs rack, and that now I need pictures/etc :( I am currently writing html in the call(env) --- what is the best way to do this?